# Is there a way to fix parts react three fiber mesh turning invisble?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, blender, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a react three fiber component from a GLTF model I created in Blender. When I apply a material, it becomes invisible at different angles.[image: Example of what I mean][image: R3F]

In blender it looks fine, so it seems that maybe it is something to do with adding a material via react three fiber causing the problem. Also when there is no material applied via React Three Fiber, there is no problem, it looks as it does in Blender. So is there any way to Conditionally apply materials to a mesh, without causing this strange invisiblity problem?[image: My model in blender:]

Really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: This definitely sounds like something to ask them, not us, over on https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues because if this is a bug, they should know about it so they can fix it for everyone, not just for you =)

Comment: This looks like an issue with the backface visibility of the material. Can you reproduce this issue with a primitive mesh (cube, sphere e.t.c) created in Blender and rendered with _react-three-fiber_?